# mysql Case select with multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query like this(longer than this):-

```
SELECT CASE
 WHEN `column1`='a' AND `column2`='b' THEN 'c'
 WHEN `column1`='d' AND `column2`='e' THEN 'f'
 WHEN `column1`='g' AND `column2`='h' THEN 'i'
   |
   |
   |
   V
 WHEN `column1`='x' AND `column2`='y' THEN 'z'
 END
```

This is only two column example. But I have 12 columns with 30 or more comparisons. Can you suggest a short method to do this(only with mysql)

like:-

```
SELECT CASE `column1` , `column2`
 WHEN 'a' AND 'b' THEN 'c'
 WHEN 'd' AND 'e' THEN 'f'
 WHEN 'g' AND 'h' THEN 'i'
   |
   |
   |
   V
 WHEN 'x' AND 'y' THEN 'z'
 END
```

Comment: Are the values in the columns always single characters (or any other fixed-length values)?

Comment: @Mureinik no. some columns have 64 of length and some columns have INTIGERS